# CreateJs how to control setTransform

Tags: text, createjs

I have the following code that is responsible for rendering a text. But currently  text is showing horizontally , any help to make the text vertical.

```
       this.shape_10 = new cjs.Text("Super", "bold 17px Arial", "#FFA632");
        this.shape_10.lineHeight = 8;
        this.shape_10.lineWidth = 13;
       this.shape_10.setTransform(-1.5, -9);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

90 belongs to rotate 90 degree in below line.

```
   this.shape_10 = new cjs.Text("Super", "bold 17px Arial", "#FFA632");
   this.shape_10.lineHeight = 8;
   this.shape_10.lineWidth = 13;
   this.shape_10.setTransform(25, -118, 1.0, 1.0, 90, 0, 0, -30, 1.0);
```